# Mac Catalyst: Popover/Sheet being dismissed after keychain access manager popover appears

Tags: swiftui, mac-catalyst

In my mac catalyst app I have a popover that shows a user a form processing status. During the process the user is required to enter password to access the keystore. So essentially keystore verification pops up asking the user to enter a password. However, the keystore verification popover dismisses the popover showing the form processing status. How do I prevent the keystore verification popover from dismissing the form processing popover?

```
VStack {
 ...
}
.popover(isPresented: $showPopover) {
PopOverView()
}
```